# Why does n-of in Netlogo selectes the same turtles in my code?

Tags: netlogo

I have a pool of turtles and I'm trying to select two random ones to play a game together. I use n-of on the turtles but sometimes n-of selects the same exact turtle twice and I have no idea why, as it should work without repetition. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? This is an extract from the code:

```
to go
  if ticks < cycleTime
  [
    playGame n-of 2 members
    tick
  ]

  if ticks = cycleTime
  [

    reset-ticks
  ]

end

to playGame[players]

  let player1 item 0 [self] of players
  let player2 item 1 [self] of players
  
  ;;sometimes it prints the exact member twice for player1 and player2
  print(player1)
  print(player2)

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not `n-of` selecting the same turtle twice.
Instead, `[self] of players` is a list that is always generated in a random order. Since you generate this list twice, both lists are not necessarily in the same order. The following should illustrate this:

```
to playGame[players]

  let thePlayers0 [self] of players
  let thePlayers1 [self] of players
  let thePlayers2 [self] of players
  print(thePlayers0)
  print(thePlayers1)
  print(thePlayers2)

end
```

Generating the list of who's just once fixes your problem:

```
to playGame[players]

  let thePlayers [self] of players
  
  let player1 item 0 thePlayers
  let player2 item 1 thePlayers
  
  print(player1)
  print(player2)

end
```

Comment: man how the hell would have I known if you didn't tell me this. Thank you!!! Is there a page on the Netlogo docs to understand a bit more about the inner workings so I don't make mistakes such as this in the future?

Comment: @MatteoBarberis I would suggest the programming guide unde agentsets (https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#agentsets)
I didn't see it right away either. I just started playing around with different numbers of agents, which clued me in that n-of wasn't the problem. Then I went looking elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Check this reproducible example using global variables, that are easier to monitor:

```
globals [
  players
  player1
  player2
]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  create-turtles 100
end

to go
  set players n-of 2 turtles
  playGame players
  tick
end

to playGame [plrs]
  set player1 item 0 [self] of plrs
  set player2 item 1 [self] of plrs
end
```

If you paste this code in your Code tab, create a monitor in the Interface for the `[self] of players` reporter, and hit `setup`+`go` (or else run `repeat 10 [show [self] of players]` in the Command Center), you will see that the two turtles' identifiers fluctuate, swapping their positions.

This brought to my mind something that I remember reading somewhere in the NetLogo documentation, but which I am unable to find: NetLogo constantly re-evaluates its variables, **even if the model is not running**.
When such variable is an agentset (such as `players` - because note that `n-of` [reports an agentset if you pass it an agentset as input](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#n-of)), or consequently depending on agentsets (such as `[self] of players`), this means that the internal ordering of the variable will be continuously shuffled.

This happens because agentsets are a random sorting of their relevant agents, and this variability is not a problem for NetLogo: on the contrary, it is at the core of its mechanism.

But in your case this means that sometimes the ordering of the `players` agentset (and therefore of the `plrs` argument, and therefore of the `[self] of plrs` list) changed in such a moment that what had been evaluated as `item 0` became `item 1` by the time `item 1` was being evaluated.

How to solve this? What doesn't change its internal ordering are lists, so you can save your `players` as a list:

```
set players sort n-of 2 turtles
```

See that `sort` [always reports a list](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sort).

This means that you can do:

```
set player1 item 0 players
set player2 item 1 players
```

and always have two different players.

If for some reason you do not want `player1` to always be the oldest turtle, just directly set `players` as the list of `self`s (as this will prevent sorting):

```
set players [self] of n-of 2 turtles
```

Comment: Thank you so much, no way I would have found this out in 1000 years on my own.  Is there a page on the Netlogo docs to understand a bit more about the inner workings so I don't make mistakes such as this in the future?

Comment: @MatteoBarberis General principles are mostly in the [User Manual](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/) (and especially in the Programming Guide), but for me the most useful source has been, and still is, the [NetLogo Dictionary](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#). It is very complete and, although its object are the details of primitive commands and reporters, it often touches on more general principles such as the one we discussed. Once you got a sufficient grounding with the Programming Guide, I would rely on the Dictionary for most of further learning.

Comment: @MatteoBarberis Of course it is not something that one can read as a guide, so experiment and play with NetLogo as much as you can and always refer to the Dictionary to understand how you can do what you are doing. Also, I think another good source is this happy niche of StackOverflow that is the NetLogo tag. Often you will find that answers are longer and more reasoned than the average in StackOverflow, so there is a lot to learn here! To be honest I learn a bunch even just answering peoples' questions, so I suggest you try and see how you would solve other peoples' problems.